# Boost API to check if the directory path is on network in c++

Tags: c++, boost

I am writing some files using my application in c++, when I save them on network drive using std::io operation the application freezes till the file is completely written, and the process is taking time whereas on local drive it does the operation very quickly.

Is there any way we can identify directory path is on a Network drive(Mapped/Non-mapped) or not? so that i can issue a warning to user, and later break the operation to save it locally first then move the file to network in background.

PS : comparing "\\" is not an option since the drive may be mapped.

Comment: "On the network" has become a fuzzy concept since iSCSI and locally cached storage. Also, the user usually knows which drives are slow in his environment. Still, you may want to defer the saving to a background thread.

Comment: Reading and writing to and from drives is slow in general; but you can minimise the effect of this procedure by preventing UI freezes. I suggest threads, where one thread deals with the i/o and the other allowing the user to do their own thing.

Comment: I agree thats why I want to find if the user path is on network or not?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for potential off-topic polemic but it seems you're on the wrong way. Any file operation can be slow, regardless the local/remote nature of the storage.

- Fragmentation makes any disk operation slower (regardless read/write)
- NTFS volumes can be split into several physical drives (some of them can be slower than another)
- Any hard drive can take arbitrary long timeout if he's trying to read damaged area (bad blocks etc.)
- Even good drive can spend noticeable time if the file is huge (making non-convenient user experience)

So it's more productive to move your disk IO to another thread to provide end-users with non-freezing UI.

Comment: I agree with you and that's the reason I am trying to identify the drive type. Later will break the operation and copy the file onto local machine then move the file to desired network path on separate thread or async write.(Edited my question with further approach)

Comment: Maybe, it's worth to test IO speed on the path provided and make a decision: to sync or to async?

Comment: before that I want to check if the path is on network? and that's my question.